# Reference request: Books/Video series on prophylaxis

Tags: books, recommendations, chess-videos, prophylaxis

I would like to imitate the prophylactic playing style of Aron Nimzowitsch, Tigran Petrosian and/or Anatoly Karpov. May I know if there are any books/video series that you would recommend?

Answer (score 3):

There are YouTube videos covering these specific areas but I'm not convinced I could recommend them. Nevertheless, here are 3 for you to try and make your own mind up. They are at least free.

[Mastering the Middlegame with Atul Dahale : Aaron Nimzowitsch : Prophylaxis!](https://youtu.be/-iHVZ3KAxl8?t=895) (link at about 15 minutes in because before that it is mostly irrelevant drivel)

[Tigran Petrosian - World Chess Champion - Master of Prophylaxis - Kingscrusher Radio Show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiJffNNCtfw) (not one of Kingcrusher's best IMHO)

[Karpov's Prophylaxis with Karpov's Prophylaxis with IM Valeri Lilov](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h82jh9EKSR4) (IM Valeri Lilov, who he?)

There are far better books if you are prepared to accept some fine games collections of these players.

**Nimzowitsch**:

Everybody is familiar with "*My System*" but "*My Praxis*" is probably better for stronger players. It is a collection of annotated games by Nimzowitsch with the intention of demonstrating "My System" in practice, kind of like the name suggests.

**Petrosian**:

Old school, perhaps, but I like PH Clarke's "*Petrosian's Best Games of Chess 1946-63*"

More modern (and with much deeper annotation) is Kasparov's "*My Great Predecessors Part 3 Petrosian Spassky*" roughly half of which is devoted to Petrosian and which includes a specific chapter on Petrosian's prophylaxis - "*Miracles of Prophylaxis*"

For **Karpov** there is more choice:

For a simple game collection there is PR Markland's "*The Best of Karpov*" but for in-depth quality annotations you can't beat the three books Kasparov wrote of the annotated games he played against Karpov:

*Kasparov vs Karpov 1975 - 1985*
*Kasparov vs Karpov 1986 - 1987*
*Kasparov vs Karpov 1988 - 2009*